# Pandas: merging two series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I'm having some real weird issues. I have a script that gets a JSON file containing some info I'm after, gene names more specifically. I had the idea of just working with it as a string, which worked just fine until I came to the point where I wanted to filter the resulting gene list with another list of genes (i.e. I'm only interested in the genes in the JSON file [file A] that are in another gene list [file B]). This is my script:

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd

pathway = ['hsa04630', 'JAK-STAT']

# Read JSON pathway data from KEGG via TogoWS REST service
link = 'http://togows.dbcls.jp/entry/pathway/' + pathway[0] + '/genes.json'
file = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
data = pd.DataFrame(file.readlines())

# Remove first and last two lines (does not contain data)
data = data.drop(data.index[[0, 1, -2, -1]])


def get_genes(string):
    """ Takes a JSON string and finds the gene ID """
    gene = str(string[0]).split(':')[1].split(';')[0].replace('"', '')
    return gene

# Filter for gene ID
data = pd.DataFrame(data.apply(get_genes, axis=1), columns=['Gene']).sort(
    'Gene')

# Filter for EGFR Core gene list
filter = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('../../Gene lists/Gene lists.xlsx',
                       sheetname='EGFR Core')['Gene'])
filtered = filter.merge(data, on='Gene')
print(filtered)
```

I have used `merge` in this fashion before, so i was very surprised when the `filtered` dataframe returned as empty. I have manually checked that there are common genes in the two different files, so that should be no problem. I'm wondering if the reason it's not working is because I'm doing something weird in the `gen_genes` function, i.e. working with strings.

Here's a placeholder for the other gene list [file B] that contains some of the genes that I manually checked, in case you want to run my script. I substitued the original [file B] with this list, and I get the same result.

```
filter = pd.DataFrame(['BRAF','KRAS','EGF','EGFR'], columns=['Gene'])
```

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `data`:

```
In [10]: data.iloc[0,0]
Out[10]: ' AKT1'
```

You will notice that there is still a space in the beginning of the string, which is the reason nothing will match.
A possible solution is to add `.strip()` to the `get_genes` function:

```
def get_genes(string):
    """ Takes a JSON string and finds the gene ID """
    gene = str(string[0]).split(':')[1].split(';')[0].replace('"', '').strip()
    return gene
```

Comment: It's always so simple... Thanks a lot, that did it!